# How to reset Hibernate sequence generators?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6-Final with an Oracle database for production and a H2 database for integration tests. The Hibernate mapping for ID creation looks like this with every entity extending EasyPersistentObject:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class EasyPersistentObject implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_seq", sequenceName = "hibernate_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_seq")
protected Integer id;
```

Before each JUnit integration test I am removing all data from the database with

```
new SchemaExport(configuration).create(false, true);
```

Everything works fine until I increment the allocationSize for sequence generation. Raising this to e.g. 10 will break several tests with UniqueKeyConstraintViolations when inserting test data.

For example:

1. Test1: Create 8 test objects (Hibernate has id values 9 and 10 still allocated)
2. Recreate database
3. Test2: Create 12 test objects (Hibernate uses 9 and 10 for IDs, then loads new IDs from database sequence which was meanwhile reseted (1-10) and fails when trying to insert a 2nd entity with ID 9)

So my question: **Is there a way to reset Hibernates allocated IDs before each test as well?**

**Addition:**
I am not using PersistenceManager from JPA but pure Hibernate SessionFactory which is created like this:

```
@Bean(name = "easySF")
public SessionFactory easySessionFactory(@Qualifier("easyConfig") AnnotationConfiguration configuration) {
    configuration.setInterceptor(new HibernateInterceptor());
    return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean(name = "easyConfig")
protected AnnotationConfiguration easyHibernateConfiguration() {
    AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    configuration.setProperties(createHibernateProperties());   
    for (Class annotatedClass : getAnnotatedClasses()) {
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
    }
    return configuration;
}
```

Do I really need to reload my whole Spring context to get the Hibernate ID generators reseted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same Problem and didn't find an inbuild way to do it. We're using hibernate 4.2.7.

After debugging deeply into hibernate I ended up extending the sequence generator. We create entities using the standard sequence generator:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SomeSeq", sequenceName = "DB_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
```

Hibernate creates an org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator for each entity. The SequnceHiLoGenerator delegates to an OptimizerFactory.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer instance.

In order to reset the sequence counters and force syncing with the database sequence you have to reset internal variables in the LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer. Unfortunately these variables are private and not modifyable. I tried to find a way using  inheritance but I didn't find an elegant solution. Finally I
created a source copy of the SequenceHiLoGenerator and extended it with a simple reset functionality:

```
public class ResetableIdGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {
               public static int cycle = 0; // global, indicating current test cycle
               protected int startingCycle = 0; // instance, indicating the test cycle the LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer was used the last time
    [...]
        public synchronized Serializable generate(final SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
            // create a new HiLoOptimizer if there's a new test cycle
            if (startingCycle < cycle) {
                hiloOptimizer = new OptimizerFactory.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer(getIdentifierType().getReturnedClass(),
                        maxLo);
                startingCycle = cycle;
            }
[....]
```

Modify the entities to use the custom generator:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "SomeSeq", strategy = "yourpackage.ResetableIdGenerator", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "DB_SEQ"), @Parameter(name = "max_lo", value = "49") })
```

Reset the sequence generator inbetween your test (@before or @after):

```
// reset Hibernate Sequences
ResetableIdGenerator.cycle++;
```

I know this isn't a good solution - It's a hack. But it works and maybe it helps to find a better solution.

EDIT 20170504: My initial post contained a mistake: The parameters "sequenceName" and "allocationSize" are JPA parameters. The GenericGenerator is from hibernate.
Instead of "sequenceName" you have to use "sequence", instead of "allocationSize" you have to use "max_lo" and set it to allocationSize-1.
I updated the code example. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer which confirms what I did not want to believe. I'm going to substitute both int attributes with a single boolean reset value and solve it with your hack. Too sad there is no clean way to do this...

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps one of the solution is to run each JUNIT test in new sessionfactory. so open and close session factory using `@Before` and `@After`

Pros

- you get sequence generators from first

Cons

- It takes a few more seconds to all JUNIT testcases

**Update**

Based on comment another way is to reset sequence in every JUNIT test in @Before method

```
ALTER SEQUENCE Test.sequence RESTART WITH 1
```

Comment: Run each test with a new sessionfactory means a Spring context reload, I fear, which is too much time-consuming and therefore not viable (a context reload takes about 15 seconds in this project and there are many integration tests)

Comment: @GreenTurtle can you try my updated answer as JUNIT uses inmemory it should be quicker

Comment: This statement won't work with Oracle (and probably not H2). But I tried to drop and recreate the sequence as well with no effect. I uses createSQLQuery for it and Hibernate does not notice the chances on the sequence this way... :-(

Comment: `ALTER SEQUENCE Test.sequence RESTART WITH 1` works with H2, thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot retest this any more but if you are running H2 with `MODE=Oracle` it probably won't work. But if you're not tight to Oracle this solution is fine.

Comment: For default H2 DB with default sequence name: `ALTER SEQUENCE public.hibernate_sequence RESTART WITH 1`. Running in cleanup.sql script after each test method: add `@Sql(scripts="classpath:cleanup.sql",executionPhase=Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)` before every test method.

Answer (score 4):

Today I faced the same problem. Since I couldn't find another solution, I tried to take the solution from OleG. Unfortunately meanwhile `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator` is marked deprecated. Therefore, I used the `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator`. If anyone else needs it, here is my customized solution:

```
public class ResettableSequenceStyleGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    private static int cycle = 0;
    private int instanceCycle = cycle;

    private Type configure_type = null;
    private Properties configure_params = null;
    private ServiceRegistry configure_serviceRegistry = null;

    private Database registerExportables_database = null;

    private SqlStringGenerationContext initialize_context = null;

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {

        configure_type = type;
        configure_params = params;
        configure_serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;

        super.configure(type, params, serviceRegistry);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {

        if (instanceCycle != cycle) {
            super.configure(configure_type, configure_params, configure_serviceRegistry);
            super.registerExportables(registerExportables_database);
            super.initialize(initialize_context);
            instanceCycle = cycle;
        }

        return super.generate(session, object);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerExportables(Database database) {

        registerExportables_database = database;

        super.registerExportables(database);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(SqlStringGenerationContext context) {

        initialize_context = context;

        super.initialize(context);
    }

    public static void resetAllInstances() {
        cycle++;
    }
}
```

Set the `ResettableSequenceStyleGenerator` as strategy in the `GenericGenerator` annotation as described in OleG's article:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "SomeSeq", strategy = "yourpackage.ResettableSequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = ...)
```

In my IntegrationTest class I then reset the sequences before each test method:

```
@Before
public void resetSequences() {
    ResettableSequenceStyleGenerator.resetAllInstances();
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to comply with latest updates to _Spring Boot 2.6.3_ and _Hibernate-Core 5.6.4_.

Answer (score 1):

guys. In my case, I didn't want to change model generators with custom classes because sequence reset was necessary for integration tests and it's not very good to adapt the code for tests.
I struggled a lot to find a solution and finally, it was found. First of all, I created a function in data.sql with the name **truncate_tables_and_sequences** name. This function truncates all the tables and resets all the sequences with **EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || quote_ident(stmt.sequencename) || ' RESTART WITH 1'**

Then after I have a custom listener for JUnit tests that is executed before each test run and this listener runs my **PostgresTestDataInitializer** that resets values for all SequenceStyleGenerator in all entities. Reflection is used to reset the counter. Not ideal, but for integration tests it's ok.

This is the code sample:

```
@Component
public class PostgresTestDataInitializer implements TestDataInitializer {

    private final TransactionUtils transactionUtils;

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username:postgres}")
    private String databaseUserName;

    public PostgresTestDataInitializer(TransactionUtils transactionUtils,
                                       EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.transactionUtils = transactionUtils;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void resetAllDbData() throws Exception {
        transactionUtils.executeInNewTransaction(this::clearAllDataAndSequences);
        resetSequenceGenerators();
    }

    private void resetSequenceGenerators() throws IllegalAccessException {
        MetamodelImpl metamodel = (MetamodelImpl)entityManager.getMetamodel();
        for(EntityPersister entityPersister : metamodel.entityPersisters().values()) {
            if (entityPersister.hasIdentifierProperty()
                    && entityPersister.getIdentifierGenerator() != null
                    && entityPersister.getIdentifierGenerator() instanceof SequenceStyleGenerator sequenceStyleGenerator
                    && sequenceStyleGenerator.getOptimizer() instanceof PooledOptimizer pooledOptimizer) {

                Field noTenantStateField = ReflectionUtils.findField(PooledOptimizer.class, "noTenantState");
                noTenantStateField.setAccessible(true);
                noTenantStateField.set(pooledOptimizer, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearAllDataAndSequences() {
        entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("truncate_tables_and_sequences")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("username", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter("username", databaseUserName)
                .execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi could you give us the full example of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

**This will force hibernate to reload its ID generators:**

myEntityManagerFactory.close();

myEntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...);

Comment: Thx, but too sad we do not use plain JPA in this project. Please see my addition in the question above.